# Stop Apache gracefully

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

Is there a way to stop the Apache server without terminating executing requests, basically a way to tell it - don't accept any more connections and shut down when you finish your current ones?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

```
apachectl -k graceful-stop
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html

Comment: Why the `-k`? I cannot find any documentation for that flag.

Comment: -k: This is an option used to send signals to the Apache processes.

Answer (score 12):

Use `apachectl -k graceful-stop` from [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#gracefulstop):

> The WINCH or
>   graceful-stop signal causes the parent process to advise the children
>   to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're
>   not serving anything). The parent will then remove its PidFile and
>   cease listening on all ports. The parent will continue to run, and
>   monitor children which are handling requests. Once all children have
>   finalised and exited or the timeout specified by the
>   GracefulShutdownTimeout has been reached, the parent will also exit.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that sys-v init used to do graceful stop by default and had force-stop as an extra option. A “special” option to gracefully stop is only needed if you run a custom process manager that normally kills processes.

Comment: This answer could give the impression that because `systemd` isn't a custom process manager it doesn't kill the process. However, by default systemd also performs a `stop` not a `graceful-stop` for apache.

Comment: @B.Miller if your systemd performs a stop instead of a graceful-stop, that's an OS-specific bug that needs to be logged. Arch Linux and CentOS 7 both perform graceful stops.

Comment: Debian does a graceful stop too

Comment: Interesting @JohnKeates ... maybe this is Ubuntu 18.04 specific. 18.04 uses the stop command `/usr/sbin/apachectl stop`